# How is the ${it} variable set in Jelly

Tags: java, jelly

I'm trying to add some functionality to a Jenkins plugin that's written in Jelly + Java.

Link to the plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin

For example, in resources/GerritServer/index.jelly:

```
            <f:entry title="${%Username}"
                     help="/plugin/gerrit-trigger/help-GerritUserName.html">
                <f:textbox name="gerritUserName"
                           value="${it.config.gerritUserName}"
                           default="${com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.gerritevents.GerritDefaultValues.DEFAULT_GERRIT_USERNAME}"/>
            </f:entry>
```

the ${it} variable is actually of type GerritTrigger, so I have access to all the public fields & methods from GerritTrigger.

My question: How is the **it** variable resolved to the type GerritTrigger? Where is this specified and how can I change it? Maybe I would like to access a method from a different class (other than GerritTrigger) using ${it}.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, it seems that if you have com/work/someapp/somelogic/someclass.java you need to put your view under /com/work/someaoo/somelogic/index.jelly and this is how index.jelly is mapped to someclass.java

Then, using ${it} inside index.jelly will give you access to the public methods & fields in someclass.java